# JavaScript splice in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Does c# has a similiar method to `splice` from JavaScript?

I only know `RemoveRange`, and this does not return the removed elements:

```
List<string> t = new List<string>();
t.RemoveRange(..., ...);
```

(I want to avoid writing my own collection).

Comment: What do you exactly want?

Comment: Get a list of the removed objects, in one method.

Comment: Not that I know of or can find. You can however extend `List` to have that functionality. __Selman22 provided exactly what I meant as answer__

Comment: It would be great if C# had this built in, so you could delete and get deleted items in one pass of a collection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no *exact* equivelant but you can write one:

```
public static List<T> Splice<T>(this List<T> source,int index,int count)
{
    var items = source.GetRange(index, count);
    source.RemoveRange(index,count);
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Ok, seems to be the best solution. because i avoid writing a new `Collection` :) One more thing, would it be the best, locking the collection during `GetRange` and `RemoveRange`?

Comment: So what about adding new elements to the collection at the same time? I'm looking for that one. I guess you gotta do everything yourself.

Answer (score 7):

If the number of spliced elements is bigger then the number of elements in a list then GetRange() throws an exception. The better solution is:

```
    public static class ListExtension
    {
      public static List<T> Splice<T>(this List<T> source, int start, int size)
      {
          var items = source.Skip(start).Take(size).ToList<T>(); 
          if (source.Count >= size)
              source.RemoveRange(start, size);
          else 
              source.Clear();
          return items;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Since C# 8 you can use [C# Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003814).

```cs
int[] someArray = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] subArray1 = someArray[0..2];               // { 1, 2 }
int[] subArray2 = someArray[1..^0];              // { 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```